# batch convert shapefiles to csv in R

Tags: csv, coordinates, multiple-columns, shapefile

I have a folder with `shapefiles`, for which i want to add 3 columns named "species", "x","y" (where x,y are the coordinates in WGS84) and then to convert in .csv format. Is that possible (assume yes) and if anybody can support in r scripting ?